# What did Paul entrust God to guard?

Tags: paul, 2-timothy

2 Timothy 1:12 NASB

> For this reason I also suffer these things, but I am not ashamed; for I know whom I have believed and I am convinced that He is able to guard what I have entrusted to Him until that day.

What did Paul entrust God to guard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BLB gives a more literal idea of the ambiguity in the Greek:

> For this reason I also suffer these things. But I am not ashamed, for
> I know whom I have believed, and I am persuaded that He is able to
> guard my deposit entrusted for that day.

That which is guarded is "my deposit", a word used in the NT, only by Paul in witing to Timothy, three times as follows:

- 1 Tim 6:20 - O Timothy, guard the **deposit committed** to you, avoiding profane, empty babblings, and opposing arguments falsely called knowledge,
- 2 Tim 1:12 - For this reason I also suffer these things. But I am not ashamed, for I know whom I have believed, and I am persuaded that He is able to guard my **deposit entrusted** for that day.
- 2 Tim 1:14 - Keep the good **deposit entrusted** to you by the Holy Spirit, the One dwelling in us.

Note that in 2 Tim 1:14, Paul is referring to that which he references in V13, namely,

> Hold on to the pattern of **sound teaching** you have heard from me, with
> the faith and love that are in Christ Jesus.

From this and the other references, we observe several things:

- The "deposit entrusted" is what God and the Holy Spirit entrust to Paul and Timothy
- That "deposit entrusted" is that of sound teaching of the Gospel of Christ and His grace toward us.  That is, as evangelists, Paul and Timothy personally felt the compelling urge of the Gospel to spread the good news of God's love and salvation through "sound teaching".  He says as much in 2 Cor 5:14 -

> For the love of Christ compels us, having concluded this, that One has
> died for all, therefore all have died.

It was this compulsion to spread the Love of God through sound teaching that Paul regarded as the "deposit entrusted" to him and Timothy that had to be guarded until Jesus returned on "that day".

Thus, while the sound teaching of the Gospel was a "deposit entrusted" to Paul and all Christians, it is still God who must guard it as 2 Tim 1:12 correctly says.  (I am personally glad about this because I am such an imperfect person and need all the divine guarding the Lord is willing to give.)

**APPENDIX - BDAG on παραθήκη**

In the above references, the "deposit entrusted" is the Greek word παραθήκη (paratheke) which BDAG defines as follows:

> property entrusted to another, deposit in imagery, in our literature
> only in the pastorals and always with φυλάσσω of the spiritual
> heritage entrusted to orthodox Christians ...

Comment: Hi Dottard! Thank you for the helpful response! I had never seen the verse that way so your exposition was very helpful (and amen about us being imperfect thank God for His guarding!). I also thought of verse 8, where Paul seems to be talking generally about the testimony of Christ, which is in line with what you shared about this referring to the Gospel/His Word.

Answer (score 1):

Dottard answered the question competently already. Here I will add a small observation.

The Paraclete (a special operation of the Holy Spirit) is God's deposit guarantee in 2 Corinthians 5:

> 5 Now the one who has fashioned us for this very purpose is God, who has given us the Spirit as a deposit [G728], guaranteeing what is to come.

There is another kind of deposit/trust in (ESV) 2 Timothy 1:

> 14 By the Holy Spirit who dwells within us, guard the good deposit entrusted to you

treasure entrusted [to you],
παραθήκην (parathēkēn)
Noun - Accusative Feminine Singular
Strong's 3866: A deposit, anything committed to one's charge or trust. From paratithemi; a deposit, i.e. trust.

We have one deposit guarding another deposit.
By the Paraclete of God's guaranteed deposit, we guard the parathéké of good deposit/treasure (the sound teaching) entrusted to us.

Comment: The verse says the opposite. God will guard his deposited. Question is what's the deposited of Paul in the verse.

Comment: I added to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> καὶ ἀπέθανε Βενιαμὶν ἑκατὸν εἰκοσιπέντε ἐτῶν ἐν γήρει καλῷ· καὶ ἔθηκαν αὐτὸν ἐν **παραθήκῃ**. Testament of Benjamin 12:2  The Greek Pseudepigrapha. Electronic text prepared by Craig A. Evans

> "And Benjamin died at last at a hundred and twenty-five years, at a good old age. And they placed him in a coffin." Testament of Benjamin 12:2  The Pseudepigrapha (English), Translated by Craig E. Evans.

> πολλάκι συνθνῄσκουσι κακοῖς᾽ οἱ συμπαρεόντες. φωρῶν μὴ δέξῃ κλοπίμην ἄδικον **παραθήκην**· Pseudo-Phocylides 1:134-135  The Greek Pseudepigrapha. Electronic text prepared by Craig A. Evans

> "Those who are with the wicked often die with them. Do not accept from thieves a deposit, stolen and unlawful." Pseudo-Phocylides 1:134-135 The Pseudepigrapha (English), Translated by Craig E. Evans.

Consulting these references and those already mentioned in this topic, I understand that the word deposit refers to the past, present and future, as a true apostolic tradition to be preserved together with the righteous and not among the marginalized.

Answer (score 0):

Timothy is the cherished responsibility of Paul, which he's confident of God to protect.

Bob Utley states on 1Tim1:18 (The charge or command, I entrust to you),

> This term is used of:
> This is a present middle indicative of paratithçmi. Paul entrusted the work of the gospel to Timothy (cf. 1 Tim. 6:20; 2 Tim. 1:14, just as Jesus had entrusted it to him, cf. 2 Tim. 1:12) to pass on to other faithful men (cf. 2 Tim. 2:2).
>
> 1. Jesus entrusting Himself to God in Luke 23:46
> 2. believers entrusting themselves to God in Acts 14:23
> 3. Paul entrusting believers to God in Acts 20:32
> 4. believers entrusting the new generation in 2 Tim. 2:2

Timothy is Paul's disciple on whom he is most confident of continuing the stewardship of God, the discipleship program of the authentic doctrines free from useless genealogies, myths and pseudo-knowledge as other churches held; the goal of which is love. The *charge* is the responsibility of stewardship given to Timothy by the Holy Spirit; Paul gives the same to his disciples, but when it comes to entrusting God, it's the loved ones, not responsibility that we entrust; thus, Timothy himself is Paul's cherished possession entrusted to God.

The word for *Charge* , Thayer:

> παραγγελία, παραγγελίας, ἡ (παραγγέλλω), properly, announcement, a proclaiming or giving a message to; hence, a charge, command: Act 16:24; a prohibition, Act 5:28; used of the Christian doctrine relative to right living, 1Ti 1:5; of particular directions relative to the same, 1Ti 1:18; plural in 1Th 4:2. (Of a military order in Xenophon, Polybius; of instruction, Aristotle, eth. Nic. 2, 2, p. 1104{a}, 7; Diodorus except p. 512, 19 (i.e. fragment book 26:1, 1).)*

The whole letter is based on reminding his disciple of the divine charge, and Paul is praying that Timothy will remain perfect in this warfare. God gives the divine charge or military responsibility to believers, but Paul as a believer has entrusted his disciples to God for safekeeping. Thus, it should be Timothy in the verse, rather than the responsibilities of sound doctrine and

This passage is the best describing the content of the responsibility for the disciple.

> [1Tim 6:13-15 ESV] I charge you in the presence of God, who gives life to all things, and of Christ Jesus, who in his testimony before Pontius Pilate made the good confession, to keep the commandment unstained and free from reproach until the appearing of our Lord Jesus Christ, which he will display at the proper time—he who is the blessed and only Sovereign, the King of kings and Lord of lords,